# Is there a way of preventing Google account password reset by a former team member who keeps changing it?

Tags: google-account, security, account-management

A former member of our team who originally had our Google account password keeps trying to modify the password and it succeeds! I think he uses the password recovery feature and succeeds in his intent by entering the creation date of the account to verify it, but he should not be allowed to do this and he's causing problems to our current team. He then not only logs in, but also changes the recovery email to his one, the recovery telephone number to his one, etc!! This is crazy... This is happening daily now and we need to find a way to permanently lock him out. We also enabled the 2 steps verification with the same results... Today we added the Google app verification (with an iPhone device of one of our current team member) hoping this will stop the problem showing a notification on the phone regarding the 3rd part attempts and being able to deny them by answering "NO" in the phone Google app popup.

But anyway we wonder if this is going to happen again... What can we do?

Comment: Beyond implementing Rubén’s answer, you might want to have your in-house counsel send this person a strongly worded C&D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to enroll your account into the advanced security program.

From [Increase security for your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7519408?hl=en)

> To add an extra layer of security to your account, you can enroll in the Advanced Protection Program. This helps protect you against common ways people hijack your account, like getting your emails, documents, contacts, and other personal data.
>
> **How the increased security works**
> To enroll in this program, you’ll need to buy two security keys.
>
> Security keys are small devices that connect to your computer, phone, or tablet. They help protect against hackers because only the person who has the key can sign in to an account. [Learn more about how security keys work](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6103523?hl%3Den%26ref_topic%3D6103521).